# Does anyone know the best ORM for Kohana that supports composite keys?

Tags: php, database, orm, kohana

Does anyone know the best ORM for Kohana that supports composite keys?I'm currently looking at using Sprig and Jelly.

http://kohana-modules.com/modules/sittercity/sprig

https://github.com/jonathangeiger/kohana-jelly

Haven't implemented either yet but will update the issue once I have a strong comparison.  On a separate note has anyone worked with both which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at LEAP? It supports composite keys and I've been using it for a large scale project and haven't had a problem.

http://orm.spadefootcode.com/